# Unable to click on Radio Button

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, radio-button, radio-group

Please, I don't know why but I can't click on this radio button.

I'm trying by xpath, css, id... but anything works.

Always I get the error: **no such element: Unable to locate element**

And I added an explicit wait, but it still not working.

Now, I'm trying it but not works as well:

WebElement radio = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='form-inputs-container']/ul/li[3]/label"));

radio.click();

**I need click on multiple destinations radio on this website:**

https://www.turismocity.com.br/

Can you help me, please ?

[RadioButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sfjrz.png)

Comment: can you provide the sample html?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your xpath is wrong Try with below xpath it will work

`//form[@class="tc-form-full-flight"]//label[@for="tt1"]/following-sibling::div`

[image]

For first radio button: `//form[@class="tc-form-full-flight"]//label[@for="tt1"]/following-sibling::div`

For second radio button: `//form[@class="tc-form-full-flight"]//label[@for="tt2"]/following-sibling::div`

For third radio button: `//form[@class="tc-form-full-flight"]//label[@for="tt3"]/following-sibling::div`

Hope this will be helpful!!!

Comment: Mohamed, it didn't work for me. I used the following xpath and now I  got the click on radio:

//*[@id='flights-tab-container']/form/div[1]/ul/li[3]/label

.Thanks a lot for your help !!! I'm so grateful !!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work `//input[@id='tt3']` or `//input[@value='MultiDestino']`

You can evaluate xpath in chrome console like this `$x("//input[@value='MultiDestino']")`

The xpath you have returned empty []

Comment: Radeesh, it didn't work for me. I used the following xpath and now I got the click on radio: //*[@id='flights-tab-container']/form/div[1]/ul/li[3]/label .Thanks a lot for your help !!! I'm so grateful !!!

Answer (score 0):

Locator is incorrect. More than that - even if it was valid, this way of finding elements is unreliable (you've used an element position - [3] in case of order change, locator will brake). I suggest css selector:

```
input[value='MultiDestino']
```

Comment: Piotr, it didn't work for me. I used the following xpath and now I got the click on radio: //*[@id='flights-tab-container']/form/div[1]/ul/li[3]/label.Thanks a lot for your help !!! I'm so grateful !!!

Answer (score 0):

For locators, you should always start with something that is highly unlikely to change. Typically that's IDs, names, and various other custom attributes depending on the site. In this site's case, the three radio buttons you are looking at each have an ID.

Side note... sometimes sites/pages don't respect HTML standards that require the ID to be unique on the page so even if your desired element has an ID, always check to make sure it's unique on the page. In this case, the IDs are unique.

To click the multiple destinations radio button, you can use the code below.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("tt3")).click();
```

In some of your comments, it looks like Selenium might be having a hard time clicking on the INPUT itself and the LABEL is working. If that's the case, then you can change the locator slightly and use the code below

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#tt3 + label")).click();
```

In the CSS selector above, # means ID and + means next sibling. See [the W3C docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#overview) for more info.